# error when runing my code in remote server: User root has exceeded the 'max_user_connections'

Tags: php, pdo, host

[Im using hostinger as host]
I have a webpage where i show the results of a query, it works locally but when i uploaded it to the web i get an error message:

> Ha habido un error en la linea: 6 Error: SQLSTATE[42000] [1226] User
>   'u749120824_root' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource
>   (current value: 3) Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   a non-object in /home/u749120824/public_html/pags/ver_usuarios.php on
>   line 18

Here are some screen shots
Localhosted
[image: Localhost]

Online Hosted
[image: Online Host]
My code:

```
class ComprobarUsuario extends Conexion{
        public function ComprobarUsuario(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function Comprobar($nombre){
            $sqlCU="SELECT * FROM admins WHERE NOMBRE=:nombre_usuario";
            $resultCU=$this->con->prepare($sqlCU);
            $resultCU->execute(array(":nombre_usuario"=>$nombre));
            $NresultadosCU=$resultCU->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($NresultadosCU!=0){
                return "admin";
            }
        }
    }
```

Connection class:

```
class Conexion{
        protected $con;
        public function Conexion(){
            try{
                $this->con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=marisol","root","");
                $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                return $this->con;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Ha habido un error en la linea: " . $e->getLine() . " Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Contact Hostinger Support.

Comment: There are only a certain number of simultaneous connections to the database server allowed. Look up the manual of the used database system and how to increase that number. Google might give you million of results on that.

Comment: This specific bit of code is probably just where the straw broke the camels back. Show where you connect to the database. Also you are only connecting once per script I assume?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i added the code of the connection

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code. You're on a cheap, shared host that has imposed severe resource limitations on your site. This is how they make money at the couple-dollars-a-month price range - if you have any sort of significant traffic, you need to go somewhere more expensive.

Comment: Because you are extending your Connecxion class in all your model classes, each model class you instantiate will ask for another conncetion to be made. With the restriction of only 3 connections per script I guess this is the 4th model class you are instantiating in this script

Comment: Out of interest this looks like old fashioned PHP i.e. using the class name as the constructor name rather than `__construct()`!

Comment: @ceejayoz Is my comment not relevant !

Comment: @RiggsFolly Your comment is relevant, but `max_user_connections` of 3 is severely limited even with a single connection per pageview. Any sort of slow query or even a couple concurrent users will crash the site quickly in this manner. Note that `max_user_connections` is per MySQL user, not per instance of the script, so that maximum is shared across OP's entire set of concurrent site visitors. A host that limits MySQL this strictly is going to be a pain to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code creates a new connection for every new instance of ComprobarUsuario. If you use similar approach for other queries your application will exceed the limitation very quickly. The solution is to create one shared connection for all sub-classes.

```
class Conexion{
        protected static $con;
        public function Conexion(){
            try{
                if (!self::$con) {
                    self::$con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=marisol","root","");
                    self::$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    self::$con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                    return self::$con;
                }
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Ha habido un error en la linea: " . $e->getLine() . " Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well 2 of us agree on this at least

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't disagree. Cool it. There's just multiple issues at play here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrej Ludinovskov. You know what you talk about!

Comment: @ceejayoz Relax man, wrote this comment before you answered my other comment. And this was not aimed at you in any way.